# Restart Script from Beginning if Failures encountered in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have around 20 transactions in my jmeter script, I need to run a load test for 2000 Users. 
I have added test checks and Assertions to validate if the transactions are passing

I want to introduce error handling , where the script start from the beginning if any of the assertions/transactions fail

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I have understood your question correctly. If your aim is to stop the workflow for the current user and start from the beginning, then you could use `until controller`.

More information on this can be found [here](http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-until-controller/).